# wp_enqueue_scripts doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, function

I created my own javascript file and now I want to integrate into my module. I'm trying to do as told in this site https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/
But it does not work, I don't understand why

P.S: I am in the main file of my module (exampe.php)

```
class exemple
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        register_activation_hook(__FILE__, array('exemple_bd', 'install'));

        register_uninstall_hook(__FILE__, array('exemple_bd', 'uninstall'));

        include_once plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'settings.php';
        new Settings();

        add_action('admin_menu', array($this, 'add_admin_menu'));
        add_action('admin_init', array($this, 'load_JS'));         
    }

    public function add_admin_menu()
    {
        add_menu_page('monTitre', 'Monplugin', 'manage_options','xxx', array($this, 'menu_html'),'dashicons-email');
        add_submenu_page('xxx', 'NouveauTitre', 'NouveauTitre', 'manage_options', 'xxx', array($this, 'menu_html'));

    }

    public function load_JS()
    {
        wp_register_script('myfunction',plugins_url( '/js/function.js', __FILE__ ));
        wp_enqueue_script('myfunction');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to register them with action hook "wp_enqueue_scripts".
Use "admin_enqueue_scripts" for admin scripts.

> The function should be called using the wp_enqueue_scripts action hook if you want to call it on the front-end of the site, like in the examples above...

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#notes

Comment: my module is for the administrator side, i dont use the front end

Comment: @KMR72 Try with "admin_enqueue_scripts"

Comment: i had already use "admin_enqueue_scripts" but the result was the same.

Comment: @KMR72 Can you share the plugin archive in a zip ? I'll check and try.

Comment: i have resolved my problem with "admin_print_scripts". thanks Karan

Answer (score 0):

if all the paths are good, an you have a custom theme, make sure your main theme file references wp_head()

it should be just before the closing 'head' tag like this:

```
<?php ...

wp_head();
 ?></head>
```